# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [multipart/form-data;boundary=XXX;charset=UTF-8]

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate, http-message-converter

I am doing multipart formdata post call from UI to upload a file.
From UI, the call goes to component A controller which you can consider it as a common component or bus which just read the stream pass the stream to other component B controller through rest call which uploads the file and sends back metadata about uploaded file in json format.

**Issue:** The call successfully goes till component B controller, file got uploaded but when the response of component B reaches component A, I am getting below error

**"message" : "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [multipart/form-data;boundary=HWhdmg6KNJw_kaP4wWnLyoAb9htc8StF4;charset=UTF-8]"**

Can someone help pls?

**Components A code**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v3/documents",consumes =  MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity uploadMultipartDocument(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)  {
    ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set(HznAppsHeaderConstant.DOCUMENT_TYPE, HznAppsUtil.getHeaderFromCustomHeaderParameterProvider(customHeaderParameterProvider, HznAppsHeaderConstant.DOCUMENT_TYPE));
    InputStream stream =null;
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> params= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    try{
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
      FileItemIterator iterStream = upload.getItemIterator(req);
      while (iterStream.hasNext()){
        FileItemStream item = iterStream.next();
        stream = item.openStream();
        if (!item.isFormField()  && item.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
          InputStreamResource inputStream = new InputStreamResource(stream) {
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
              return item.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() {
              return -1;
            }
          };
          params.add("file", inputStream);
          break;
        }
      }
      final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(params, headers);
      restTemplate.getInterceptors().clear();
      SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
      requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
      restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
      responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("Component B URL", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Object.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseEntity;
  }
```

**Component B code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v3/documents", produces = {"application/json"}, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity uploadMultipartDocument(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ResponseDocument responseDocument = null;
        try {
            responseDocument = documentsService.uploadMultiPartDocument(request,documentType); // Doing Soap call to upload document and its works fine in this method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDocument, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis I see in past you have answered similar question.Can you help here ?

Comment: please dont explain your code, post your code

Comment: Updated with code snipet

Comment: did you validate what ever component B is returning is expected?

Comment: Yes, I validated by calling component B using postman, and its expected response as below

{
  "documentName" : "New doc",
  "responseUri" : "New doc~~92402881491000.docx"
}

but when I call component A in postman instead of getting above response I got the error pasted in title.